# Convert the format of a date in Java/Typescript for searchpurposes

Tags: java, date

I search for a while now, but I didn't found what I need to solve my problem.

First of,I have a "add reminder page" in my app to add reminder with some inputs and the date / time:

```
<ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-label class="ion-label-links" >{{"Datum"|translate}}</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col text-right>
        <ion-label class="ion-label-reminder-rechts">{{"Uhrzeit"|translate}}</ion-label>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="schnurr">
      <ion-col>
        <ion-datetime class="ion-input-reminder" displayFormat="DD.MM.YYYY" [(ngModel)]="reminder.myDate" ></ion-datetime>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-datetime text-right class="ion-input-reminder-r" displayFormat="HH:mm" minuteValues="0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55" [(ngModel)]="reminder.myTime" ></ion-datetime>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

And I set a standard date/time with this function:

```
formatLocalDate() {

    var now = new Date(),
        tzo = -now.getTimezoneOffset(),
        dif = tzo >= 0 ? '+' : '-',
        pad = function(num) {
            var norm = Math.abs(Math.floor(num));
            return (norm < 10 ? '0' : '') + norm;
        };
    return now.getFullYear() 
        + '-' + pad(now.getMonth()+1)
        + '-' + pad(now.getDate())
        + 'T' + pad(now.getHours())
        + ':' + pad(now.getMinutes()) 
        + ':' + pad(now.getSeconds()) 
        + dif + pad(tzo / 60) 
        + ':' + pad(tzo % 60);
  }
```

Okay, everything is fine. I Save the record in my couchDb and it looks like this:

```
2017-07-05T09:18:24+02:00
```

Now the problem with this kind of format is that I implemented a search field but the usual format here is "dd.mm.yyyy" and not the ISO format, so I formated the output in my app like this:

```
<br><font size="1">{{item.doc.myDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm'}} Uhr</font>
```

but if I search for that item, it doesn't work, because the variable is still in the old format.

My search is looking like this:

```
.....
 <ion-item *ngIf="!searchvariable || item.doc.xName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchvariable) 
                       || item.doc.myDate.toDateString().includes(this.searchvariable)"  class="ion-item1" tappable (click)="openReminder(reminder.doc)" style="background-color: oldlace">
        {{item.doc.myDate.toDateString()}}
......
```

The search is working for everything but the date. (because of the formatproblems)
Is there a possibility to do something like "reminder.myDate.format(xxx)" or something like this?
I mean, it's possible to alter the output, is there a similar way for my search?!

Btw. I have to format the date with this function, otherwise I get errors because the datepicker needs this format.

Thank you!